# How does Authentication works in asp.net core3.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I have the following code in Startup.cs file

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.
        AddAuthentication("CookieAuth").
        AddCookie("CookieAuth", config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "user.cookie";
            config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
        });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();//determining a user's identity
    app.UseAuthorization();//determines what a user is able to do

    app.UseEndpoints(opt => {
        opt.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

The above configuration works fine, it doesn't have any exception. But I can't figure out how the **Authentication** works. I have known the following concepts:

1. **Authentication** determines the user's identity.
2. **Authorization** determines what a user is able to do.

I didn't know the execution sequential. I mean:

1. does the **Authentication** always check the user's identity per request? Even though these requests are in the same session?
2. What's will happen if a request doesn't have a valid user's identity(e.g: on the first request)? is it going to continue executing the **Authorization**?

Comment: Please read this official artical which may help you solve your questions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.0